# Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

$$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* = \{\overline{m} \mid 0 < m \leq n-1,\;\gcd(n,m)=1\}.$$

Show that $((\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*,\times)$ is a group where $\times$ is integer multiplication modulo $n$.

Here $\overline{x}$ means $x + kn$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I was able to prove associativity and existence of identity (which is $\overline{1}$) but was not able to prove the existence of the inverse. Any help?

Comment: Hint: use Bezout's identity.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noted, the identity element is $\overline{1}$ and thus, finding an inverse for $\overline{m}$ is equivalent to finding a solution $x$ to the congruence-equation
$$xm = 1 \mod n.$$

Now this is by definition equal to the fact that $n \mid (xm - 1)$, or written differently, $xm-1 = kn$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. The latter can be further modified to the form
$$1 = xm-kn.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

So, finding an inverse for $\overline{m}$ is equivalent to finding $k,x\in \mathbb{Z}$, that satisfy \eqref{1}.

Now if $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, what can we tell about the existence of a solution? The extended euclidean algorithm might give a hint.

**Edit:** or as [Suzet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/562979/suzet) noted, Bézout's identity.